# How to access build directory in Qt creator in PRO file

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake

I have an application which have three plugins 
All the plugins(dlls) are created into one lib directory($PWD../bin/lib) and main application destination($PWD/../DestDebug/myApp) is set using QTCreator "destination directory".

My intention is whichever the destination directory my pro file should be capable of copying all dlls into main application destination directory.

Tried this in windows

```
BINARY_PATH = $$PWD/Bin/debug
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(copy /Y $$shell_path($$BINARY_PATH)\*.dll  $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\debug$$escape_expand(\\n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Read that from qt documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#installs